# Проблема обращение к сети в основном потоке

Tags: java, android, сеть, асинхронность

Думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что android запрещает обращаться к сети из основного потока. Все библиотеки в основном предполагают, что они могут выполняться как синхронно так и асинхронно. Например, я использую [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync), для работы с `websocket`. Если использовать их в асинхронном стиле, то так или иначе они предполагают создание класса `Callback`, который определяет поведение, после того, как вопрос будет выполнен. В конечном счете, если писать в таком стиле при множественном обращении к сети эти классы получаются вложенными друг в друга.

**UPD**
На текущий момент у меня есть код вида:

```
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().getJSONArray(url, new AsyncHttpClient.JSONArrayCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse response, JSONArray result) {
        if (e != null) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
       //Для примера получаем url из нашего JSONArray
       String url = gettingNewDataParsedFromJSONArray(result);
       Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();
       //А здесь мы имеем еще один коллбэк
       client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
         @Override 
         public void onFailure(Request request, IOException throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
         }

         @Override 
         public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

            //А если после получения и обработки результата мне нужно совершить еще одно обращение к сети?
            //создавать еще один анонимный класс?
          }
          System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Как правильно поступать в такой ситуации? Использовать `AsyncTask` и внутри неё вызывать синхронные версии методов?

Comment: "если писать в таком стиле при множественном обращении к сети эти классы получаются вложенными друг в друга" В чем именно вы видите проблему, у вас большая цепочка последовательных запросов/обработчиков, которые вы хотите сделать параллельными?

Comment: Попытался проиллюстрировать проблему кодом. По сути, мне нужна последовательная обработка.